# VB.NET MS Project how to bring a form in front of the application?

Tags: ms-project

I have a form as part of a VSTO Project application. For various reasons it can end up behind the main Project application window. How do I bring it back to the front? I've tried form.activate and form.bringtofront, but neither of those commands do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code that I use to show/re-show forms in vb.net MS Project add-ins. If the form gets behind another window, calling ShowTkForm will bring it back to the front:

```
Friend formTk As tk
Friend Sub ShowTkForm()
    If formTk Is Nothing OrElse formTk.IsDisposed Then
        formTk = New tk
    End If
    formTk.Show()
End Sub
```

Note: for modeless forms, use the `.Show` method, otherwise use `.ShowDialog`.

For modeless forms, I also like to set the owner of the form as the MS Project application to keep them together. In the Load event of the form:

```
    Dim ip As IntPtr = FindWindowByCaption(0, ProjApp.Caption)
    SetWindowLong(New HandleRef(Me, Me.Handle), GWL_HWNDPARENT, New HandleRef(Nothing, ip))
```

Which requires:

```
Friend Const GWL_HWNDPARENT = (-8)
<DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SetWindowLong", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
Private Function SetWindowLongPtr32(ByVal hWnd As HandleRef, ByVal nIndex As Integer, ByVal dwNewLong As HandleRef) As IntPtr
End Function
<DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SetWindowLongPtr", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
Private Function SetWindowLongPtr64(ByVal hWnd As HandleRef, ByVal nIndex As Integer, ByVal dwNewLong As HandleRef) As IntPtr
End Function
Friend Function SetWindowLong(ByVal hWnd As HandleRef, ByVal nIndex As Integer, ByVal dwNewLong As HandleRef) As IntPtr
    If (IntPtr.Size = 4) Then
        Return SetWindowLongPtr32(hWnd, nIndex, dwNewLong)
    End If
    Return SetWindowLongPtr64(hWnd, nIndex, dwNewLong)
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="FindWindow", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
Friend Function FindWindowByCaption(ByVal zero As IntPtr, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Rachel! Will try that this week and get back.

Comment: Whatever that did, it causes the form to stay in front of the application no matter which project you pick. Not sure if I like that or not, but I think it answers the question.

Comment: Or, is there a way to set the forms owner to the specific active project instead of the application?

Comment: How is this different from setting the forms TopMost property to True?

Comment: The owner of a window has to be another window and all projects are in the same window (e.g. the application), but you could tie an instance of the form to a project like in your other post to hide/show it when a project is activated: [How to iterate through open forms in a VSTO add-in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48885969/how-to-iterate-through-open-forms-in-a-vsto-add-in).

Comment: Got it. Quick note: I had to use the word "Shared" in the DllImport function declarations for this to compile.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want your form to be [modal](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12045/what-is-a-modal-dialog-window). I'm not sure what form library you're using, but if this were a MS Project VBA form, then you'd set the form's .ShowModal property to True: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/showmodal-property.

Presuming you're using a .NET form, this may be more appropiate: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Nope, definitely do NOT want modal. I want the user to be able to leave the form and go back to the parent so they can look some things up, or switch to a different project. But, when they click a certain button I want to bring the open form to the top of the visible stack. So far, nothing works; the visible stack always defaults to the project window and nothing I can come up with in code will bring the form forward. The only thing that works is to manually click on the icon down in the task bar.